# django-'module' object has no attribute 'editmode' error.

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I am trying to develop an application in Django.
I have a project named ajax_tut and app named myApp
The `ajax_tut/urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myApp import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^myApp/', include('myApp.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My myApp/urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myApp import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^$', views.editmode))
```

And myApp/views.py looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
def editmode(request):
    return render_to_response('myApp/editmode.html')
```

When I try to run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp`, I get an error `'module' object has no attribute 'editmode'`.I am new to django. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

> Blockquote

Comment: It worked properly when I changed the content of `editmode function` in `myApp/views.py` to return `HttpResponse("I am good")`

Comment: The error is probably due to incorrect code formatting, meaning the `editmode` function doesn't "exist" to python. When you changed it to return `HttpResponse("I am good")` maybe you inadvertently fixed the formatting as well.

Comment: the difference between returning `HttpResponse("I am good")` and returning the result of `render_to_response('myApp/editmode.html')` is not relevant to the error you saw and both should work

Comment: `editmode` was a function I had defined in views.py. The problem was with the path I had wrongly specified in the HTML code(the template).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the path I had wrongly specified in the HTML code(the template). 
I had wrongly specified the path for a javascript file in the model(I had specified it as `static/js/pramukhime.js` instead of `/static/js/pramukhime.js`-the leading / was missing).
On correcting that the problem was solved.